# Using JavaScript to create a .doc file

Tags: javascript, file-io, doc

Is it possible to create a .doc format file in JavaScript?
Currently I have a Mozilla addon which creates .txt files but curious to see if it could be extended to .doc ..

```
file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
                     .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
file.initWithPath(fullPathToFile);

if (file.exists() === false) 
    {file.create(Components.interfaces.nsIFile.NORMAL_FILE_TYPE, 420);}

var outputStream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"]
                    .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileOutputStream),
converter = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/intl/converter-output-stream;1"]
                    .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIConverterOutputStream);


outputStream.init(file, 0x02 | 0x08 | 0x20, 420, 0);
converter.init(outputStream, "UTF-8", 0, 0);
converter.writeString('\n --------------------------------------------------- \n');
converter.close();
```

Comment: While it should be possible, you might want to look at RTF files which will be *much* easier to create -- if you rename them as a 'DOC' file, very few people will know the difference.  If you are doing a form letter with search-and-replace fields, those are super-easy to do as an RTF.

Comment: was hoping for an actual `.doc`, instead of `.rtf` workaround